# How can i draw an object before its parent object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, rendering

How can i change the sorting layer of objects in Unity 2D? Like force an object be rendered above (or under) another object even if it is a child of the other object.

I'm making a simple 2D humanoid animation, intuitively i'm using the torso as the root object, and the arms and legs be the child of it. But it results that my left arms is rendered after the torso, so it looks like my character have 2 right arms.

I tried to change the Z value of my arm, change the layer from UI to others, and tried to change some settings in my Canvas. But none of it worked.

I'm using RawImage to render my character, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the sorting layers? Unity allows defining sorting layers for 2d sprites. You can select a sorting layer in the sprite renderer component,
You can create and order them under: Under "Tags and layers"
[image: inspector add layer]

You can also order sprites on the same layer by changing the "order in layer" value in the sprite renderer component.

Comment: I see, i believe that is the problem. I'm using a rawimage from UI, so i don't have a sprite renderer component and no sorting layers. Thank you for the help.